# How to check for same person with different birthday?

Tags: r

I have this dataset

```
ID   DoB
1111 01/01/2000
2222 03/04/2001
3333 07/22/2002
1111 02/01/2000
2222 03/04/2001
```

Can you please advise how can i create a script that checks for DoB inconsisntencies in case the same ID has different DoB so i get an error

> ID 1111 has DoB inconsistencies. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done by many ways.  An option is to check for number of distinct 'DoB' for each 'ID' and then create a 'msg'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    # // grouped by ID
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    # // filter ID with different DoB
    filter(n_distinct(DoB) > 1) %>%
    # // get the distinct elements
    distinct(ID) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    # // create a glue interpolated message
    summarise(msg = glue::glue("ID {ID} has DoB inconsistencies.  Please check")) %>% 
    pull(msg)
#ID 1111 has DoB inconsistencies.  Please check
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
cat(sprintf("ID %s has DoB inconsistencies. Please check", 
        names(which(table(unique(df1)$ID) > 1))), "\n")
#ID 1111 has DoB inconsistencies. Please check
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1111L, 2222L, 3333L, 1111L, 2222L), DoB = c("01/01/2000", 
"03/04/2001", "07/22/2002", "02/01/2000", "03/04/2001")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your approach. is there a way to count the number of lines after `pull(msg)` and save the msg to a dataframe?

Comment: @AndresMora You can either use `nrow(.)` before the `pull` or the `%>% length(.)` after the pull.  Create an object i..e out <- df1 %>% .... %>% pull(msg); length(out)`

Comment: @AndresMora if you need a data.frame, then don't `pull(msg)`.  The `summarise` output is a `data.frame/tibble`

Answer (score 2):

a possible alternative solution in base are would be this:

```
library(data.table) #needed to read table from text
# dummy data you supplied
df <- data.table::fread("ID   DoB
1111 01/01/2000
2222 03/04/2001
3333 07/22/2002
1111 02/01/2000
2222 03/04/2001") %>% 
  as.data.frame()


# reduce data to unique comibations
u_df <- unique(df)
# get first repetition (there should be none if DoB is unique per ID
rep_df <- u_df[duplicated(unique(u_df)$ID), ]
# Print ID from result set inside the given sentence
print(paste("ID", rep_df$ID,  "has DoB inconsistencies. Please check"))

[1] "ID 1111 has DoB inconsistencies. Please check"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `add_count` and `arrange`:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1111L, 2222L, 3333L, 1111L, 2222L), DoB = c("01/01/2000", 
                                                                  "03/04/2001", "07/22/2002", "02/01/2000", "03/04/2001")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                              -5L)) %>% 
    dplyr::add_count(ID) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(desc(n))
```

Output:

```
    ID        DoB number_of_DoB
1 1111 01/01/2000             2
2 2222 03/04/2001             2
3 1111 02/01/2000             2
4 2222 03/04/2001             2
5 3333 07/22/2002             1
```

Clearly, any ID with number_of_DoB != 1 is inconsistent.